# tkinter label image not updating with .update_idletasks()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an issue where my image label will not update. I have used a large combination of root.update() root.update_idletasks() etc, I have also gone through many posts around the internet attempting to use their solutions but to no avail.

I have the code split to one class and two functions, the first function will check if the user has the right spelling or not, the second will pick a new random word and image from a dict.

The issue is that the image will not update, the print command is working so the class and funcs are working fine.

here is the code thus far, I am new to using Class and **init** I thought the best way to test out the .update of tkinter is a spelling game

```
from tkinter import *
import random

words = {"apple": "apple.gif", "car": "car.gif"}

MAIN_FONT = "Helvetica", 16

root = Tk()
class mainFrame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pick_random = "..."

        #MAIN TITLE OF THE APP
        main_title = Label(root, text="Spelling", font=MAIN_FONT)
        main_title.pack()
        #END OF MAIN TITLE

        #START OF IMAGE
        self.img = PhotoImage(file=self.pick_another() + ".png")

        self.show_image = Label(root, image=self.img)
        self.show_image.configure(image=self.img)
        self.show_image.image = self.img
        self.show_image.pack()
        #END OF IMAGE

        #START OF ENTRY AND BUTTON INPUTS
        self.main_entry = Entry(root)
        self.submit_btn = Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.submit)

        self.main_entry.pack()
        self.submit_btn.pack()
        #END OF ENTRY AND BUTTON INPUTS

    def submit(self):
        if self.main_entry.get() == self.pick_random:
            print("RIGHT")
            self.pick_another()
        else:
            print("That's not right, try again")

    def pick_another(self):
        print("Called")
        self.pick_random = random.choice(list(words.keys()))
        print(self.pick_random)
        root.update_idletasks()
        return self.pick_random

app = mainFrame()
root.mainloop()
```

As I said this does kind of work, The first image will show up and inputting the correct spelling for the image will generate a new word but the image does not update.

I have spent a few days working on various scripts trying to get tkinter to update, but it will not.

I would be very grateful for any help in this

Comment: there are mistakes in your indentation

Comment: You only use _self.show_image.configure(image=self.img)_ once in the program so that is the only image that will show.  Also _if self.main_entry.get() == self.pick_random:_ will never be equal so pick_another is not called.  Add a print statement to see what values you are testing for equality, i.e. _print(self.main_entry.get(), self.pick_random)_.

Comment: Bryan Oakley: There was some indentation issues when pasting it onto this site, that may be what you are seeing, Pycharm takes care of much of my indentation.                                                                                                                Curly Joe, There should only be one image on the app, it gets randomly changed. The issues is that tkinter will not update the image. The if statement you mentioned is getting called as print("Right") is being called. I have tried a number of other things tonight and still no fix. Its just something I am missing